# STOP a looped script ran on a server?

Tags: shell, loops, ssh, server

I created a robot. The robot is run like this :

```
import os

while True:
    print("RUN Script")
    os.system("./trading_bot.py")
    print("STOP Scriptt")
```

Actually, it works on my computer then I can stop it by closing the terminal.

However, I would like to put it on my ODROID (kind of raspberry).

I will need to connect through SSH and run the script. However, I am wondering how to stop this infinite loop, because if I close my computer terminal windows, it will not affect what is ran on the ODROID I think... Same question if I loose SSH connection with ODROID, how to get access back to the running script?

I need some explanation about all this works.

Comment: The running script will be a child of your shell process. If you close the SSH session, both will be killed. Check out `screen` oder `tmux` to make running processes survive your session.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you tell me how to run the script even if I close SSH session ?

Comment: Usually, `nohup` can do the trick. 'nohup script.py`, `man nohup` for more info